# Minimize button click event (App_EnteredBackgroundAsync) is not invoking in Windows Target Share event of UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp

My FileTransfer app using **Launcher.LaunchUriAsync**(...) to launch my application for **windows target share operations** by creating new Frame, if rootFrame is null. After launch the application, the minimize button event(**App_EnteredBackgroundAsync**) did not invoked (while click on minimize button). Anyone have any idea regarding this? How can I resolve this?

Here bello is the code flow:

```
private static readonly string SHARE_TARGET_URI = "myappprotocol://right-click-share";
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
      try
      {
            args.ShareOperation.ReportStarted();
                
            Uri uri = new Uri(SHARE_TARGET_URI);

            ShareOperation shareOperation = args.ShareOperation;
            //Performed some file url save operation from shared uri data
                
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
            args.ShareOperation.ReportCompleted();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
                
       }
}
```

**LunchUriAsync**(...) will fire  **OnActivated**(...) event:

```
  protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
      try
      {
          //Performed some needed operations
          
      if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
          {
          //Performed toast operation
          }

          if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol || args.Kind == ActivationKind.ProtocolForResults)
          {
          setSharePage(args); 
          }

      //Performed some needed operations          
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          
      }      
  }


 private void setSharePage(IActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
     try
     {
         Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
         if (rootFrame == null)
         {
             rootFrame = new Frame();
             rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;
             Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
         }
        
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MySharePageView), args);
        Window.Current.Activate();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         
     }
 }
```

Now process the saved shared files URI in **OnNavigatedTo** event of **MySharePageView.cs** page.

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      var activatevArgs = e.Parameter as IActivatedEventArgs;

      if (activatevArgs?.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
      {
          ProtocolActivatedEventArgs protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)activatevArgs;

          if (protocolArgs?.Uri?.AbsolutePath == SHARE_TARGET_ROUTE)
          {
              // Performed share page url processing operation that was stored in OnShareTargetActivated operation
          }
      }
}
```

All the operation works well except minimize event (App_EnteredBackgroundAsync). It's not fired due to click on minimize button.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Target Source App will open the Target Share App, why you use `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);` to run the Target Share app itself?

Comment: Hello @JunjieZhu-MSFT Main purpose of our application is to transfer file. we have different page/view , one is mainView another is shareView. We launch shareView in case of Right click Context menu and ShareTarget. We have used LunchUriAsync to release the app from where sharetarget has been called. Otherwise ShareTarget Luncher app( like Windows file explorer) will be blocked untril default shareview reported complete.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, For rightClick context we have used MS-Explorer command verb sample code, where everything worked fine. Like minimize click event work smoothly. We want to maintain same UX for RightClick-Context and ShareTarget ,that's why we are launching URI to fire OnActivate Event. Microsoft commandverb dll call this OnActivate event due to rightClick. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/samples-explorercommandverb

Comment: I write a Share Target sample, and my `App_EnteredBackground` works fine. Could you reproduce your problem in a blank project? so that we can further troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Thanks for your reply. I'll create a sample project and will share the github link here.

Comment: Great! Please let me know if there are any updates.